# displaying dropdown items as nav-items instead of pop-up list

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
.dashBoard {
  width: 250;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: mediumaquamarine;
 
}

.navbar-nav > li > .nav-link {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 0px !important;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/coreStyleSheet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-10 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="dashBoard animated slideInLeft" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Module 1
            </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> 
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Module 2
            </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> 
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Module 3
            </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> 
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have a side bar `nav` which is on the left and all the items are placed on below the other and I have a drop down but the problem is when I click it comes as a pop-up window,what I wish is like which the dropdown is clicked the items below that should move down and the list show appear.

I want something like this

[image]

Please guide me to achieve this.

Comment: I converted your code to snippet, can you make it a little bit closer to what you described as being your current state?

Comment: I am using bootstrap 4 and running the snippet from here is not my current state. let me put up a fiddle for you. Give me a sec.

Comment: You can include external assets into snippets on SO, it's almost as good as fiddles.

Comment: hey ! I have added the snippet in here. Please recheck my question and run the snippet. How you will get my current status. @SergChernata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite an easy conversion. Mostly just getting rid of `absolute` positioning and some styling flourishes such as rounded corners.

```css
.dashBoard {
  width: 250;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: mediumaquamarine;
 
}

.navbar-nav > li > .nav-link {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 0px !important;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

div.dropdown-menu{
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius:0;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/coreStyleSheet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-10 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="dashBoard animated slideInLeft" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Module 1
            </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> 
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Module 2
            </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> 
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Module 3
            </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> 
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `display:static` was the issue?

Comment: For the most part, yes. Rather, display: absolute breaks the element out of the natural flow, so it had no effect on elements around it. Static places it back into the flow.

Comment: yeah thanks. I didn't knew about that. Thanks Bud :)